# Laravel App\Event How can I check if this data is coming?

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

How can I check if this data is coming? ($this->message->receiver_id)

```
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

public $message;
 
public function __construct(Message $message)
{
    $this->message = $message;
}
 
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('privatechat.'.$this->message->receiver_id);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... 1st check in network tab it is successfully subscribe or not  . then console the event from echo

Comment: How do you explain a little bit, I'm new on this

Comment: chrome dev tool have network tab there you can filter `ws` and check websocket events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `Log::info` to check it.

```
public function __construct(Message $message)
{
    \Log::info(['message'=>$message]);
    $this->message = $message;
}
```

If the `__construct` will run your log will be stored in `storage/log` file

Comment: success :)

I could not find the way (storage/log) but 
 Log::create(['info' => $this->message->receiver_id]);  
I saved it to the database

Comment: Yes if you have enabled your log to DB it wil store in DB.